# Missing suitable constructor

Tags: constructor, copy-constructor, implicit-conversion

I have the following class (this is not my real class, but just for illustration purposes):

```
class Number {
public:
    Number() : value_(0) {}

    explicit Number(int v) : value_(v) {}

    Number(const Number & other){
        value_ = other.value_;
    }

    Number& operator=(const int & v){
        value_ = v;
        return *this;
    }

private:
    int value_;
};
```

I can do the following and they all work correctly:

```
void test_ok(){
    Number x(3);
    Number y = Number(3);
    Number y2(x);
    Number y3 = x;
    Number u;
    u = 3;
}
```

However, the following gives this compiler error: no suitable constructor exists to convert from "int" to "Number"

```
void test_error(){
    Number z = 3;
}
```

If I comment the word "explicit" from the second constructor, then the compiler error is gone and apparently the automatic conversion works fine. Since I would like to keep the keyword "explicit", which constructor am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `explicit` keyword prohibits implicit automatic typecasting. In your test `Number z = 3` you're doing exactly that - implicit typecasting, from an `int` (3) to a `Number`. The compiler rightfully prohibits that.

If you want to keep the keyword `explicit` then you'll have to construct the `Number` object as `Number(3)` (as you'd already noticed and written).

In short, there is no other constructor that you can use if you want to keep the `explicit` keyword. Whatever you do, implicit typecasts will be prohibited.

Comment: Thanks, so I guess this is just not possible. I am just wondering which default conversion is using the compiler when I remove the <explicit> keyword and if it could be possible to overload that.

Comment: The implicit conversion that you allow by removing the keyword `explicit` is to typecast 3 to a `Number`. You get the same behavior when you use `Number z = static_cast<Number>(3);` and in that case you can keep the `explicit` keyword, because well.. you're handling the typecast yourself explictly ;-)